# ExtJS - any theme tester similar to Dojo's?

Tags: extjs, dojo

For someone new to JavaScript framework I have to say this page really got me drooling in awe.

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=claro#bogus

Is there a similar theme tester or show case like this for ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep there is an official themes tester to be found here [Extjs Theme Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/themes/index.html), its not as complete as the Dojo one; but still useful.